# HDFS for Teradata

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, teradata

As per my understanding, HDFS is useful for the data that is unstructured and large in quantity. I wanted to know, is it possible to use HDFS with Teradata, as Teradata is RDBMS and **hence not so Unstructured**?

Also, how does HDFS come into picture with the database anyway. Is it that the File System contains data or , how exactly does it work in simple terms? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Teradata DB itself - no.

However:), Teradata is providing so-called **UDA** (**Unified Data Architecture**), where Teradata, Aster DB and Hadoop(HDFS) are interconnected and can work together almost seamlessly :).

In general, if you want to work with unstructured data only, choose Aster. Which is product of Teradata and you can be connect with HDFS directly. HDFS is used here as a cheap and fast data storage.

Even more interesting solution will come up with the new Aster version (6), where **AFS** (**Aster File system**) is going to be implemented. ASR is a distributed filesystem similar to HDFS. I'm looking forward to give a try as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

To add some more details to the answer of xhudik.

To connect Teradata with Hadoop, you need a connector. One is called Teradata QueryGrid for Hadoop. It is an addon to Teradata DWH and connects to HCatalog. And HCatalog connects to HDFS.

You can also use the Teradata Connector for Hadoop, which is a SQOOP extension and so you can connect to Teradata from Hadoop.